# no space between words in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I just looked at my MySQL data not all the words are joined up! For example if the word are `David Greene`, it will show them as `DavidGreene`.

How can I put the space where there should be one?

The data is dynamic by the way. Edit: here is the code:

```
<?php
$errorMsg = "";
// First we check to see if the form has been submitted 
if (isset($_POST['username'])){
    //Connect to the database through our include 
    include_once "scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
    // Filter the posted variables
    $username = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $_POST['username']); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $country = ereg_replace("[^A-Z a-z0-9]", "", $_POST['country']); // filter everything but spaces, numbers, and letters
    $state = ereg_replace("[^A-Z a-z0-9]", "", $_POST['state']); // filter everything but spaces, numbers, and letters
    $city = ereg_replace("[^A-Z a-z0-9]", "", $_POST['city']); // filter everything but spaces, numbers, and letters
    $accounttype = ereg_replace("[^a-z]", "", $_POST['accounttype']); // filter everything but lowercase letters
    $email = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
    $email = strip_tags($email);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $password = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $_POST['password']); // filter everything but numbers and letters
        $passport = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $_POST['passport']); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    // Check to see if the user filled all fields with
    // the "Required"(*) symbol next to them in the join form
    // and print out to them what they have forgotten to put in
    if((!$username) || (!$country) || (!$state) || (!$city) || (!$accounttype) || (!$email) || (!$password) || (!passport)){

        $errorMsg = "You did not submit the following required information!<br /><br />";
        if(!$username){
            $errorMsg .= "--- User Name";
        } else if(!$country){
            $errorMsg .= "--- Country"; 
        } else if(!$state){ 
            $errorMsg .= "--- State"; 
       } else if(!$city){ 
           $errorMsg .= "--- City"; 
       } else if(!$accounttype){ 
           $errorMsg .= "--- Account Type"; 
       } else if(!$email){ 
           $errorMsg .= "--- Email Address"; 
       } else if(!$password){ 
           $errorMsg .= "--- Password";
       } else if(!$passport){ 
           $errorMsg .= "--- Passport";
       }
    } else {
    // Database duplicate Fields Check
    $sql_username_check = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1");
    $sql_email_check = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1");
    $username_check = mysql_num_rows($sql_username_check);
    $email_check = mysql_num_rows($sql_email_check); 
    if ($username_check > 0){ 
        $errorMsg = "<u>ERROR:</u><br />Your User Name is already in use inside our system. Please try another.";
    } else if ($email_check > 0){ 
        $errorMsg = "<u>ERROR:</u><br />Your Email address is already in use inside our system. Please try another.";
    } else {
        // Add MD5 Hash to the password variable
       $hashedPass = md5($password); 
        // Add user info into the database table, claim your fields then values 
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (username, country, state, city, accounttype, email, password, passport, signupdate) 
        VALUES('$username','$country','$state','$city','$accounttype','$email','$hashedPass','$passport',now())") or die (mysql_error());
        // Get the inserted ID here to use in the activation email
        $id = mysql_insert_id();
        // Create directory(folder) to hold each user files(pics, MP3s, etc.) 
        mkdir("memberFiles/$id", 0755); 
        // Start assembly of Email Member the activation link
        $to = "$email";
        // Change this to your site admin email
        $from = "admin@somewebsite.com";
        $subject = "Complete your registration";
        //Begin HTML Email Message where you need to change the activation URL inside
        $message = '<html>
        <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        Hi ' . $username . ',
        <br /><br />
        You must complete this step to activate your account with us.
        <br /><br />
        Please click here to activate now &gt;&gt;
        <a href="http://www.netolancer.co.uk/bitcoin/activation.php?id=' . $id . '">
        ACTIVATE NOW</a>
        <br /><br />
        Your Login Data is as follows: 
        <br /><br />
        E-mail Address: ' . $email . ' <br />
        Password: ' . $password . ' 
        <br /><br /> 
        Thanks! 
        </body>
        </html>';
        // end of message
        $headers = "From: $from\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
        $to = "$to";
        // Finally send the activation email to the member
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        // Then print a message to the browser for the joiner 
        print "<br /><br /><br /><h4>OK $firstname, one last step to verify your email identity:</h4><br />
        We just sent an Activation link to: $email<br /><br />
        <strong><font color=\"#990000\">Please check your email inbox in a moment</font></strong> to click on the Activation <br />
        Link inside the message. After email activation you can log in.";
        exit(); // Exit so the form and page does not display, just this success message
    } // Close else after database duplicate field value checks
  } // Close else after missing vars check
} //Close if $_POST
?>
```

Comment: show us your code ???......

Comment: show us how you store that values..

Comment: i never heard of such a thing happening. and i don't see how this should be reversible without the original information.

Comment: What do you think `ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $_POST['username'])` is doing?

Comment: You should not use ereg_* functions any more. These functions are deprecated.

Comment: @Gung Foo, All the words are joined up. the addresses, the names etc etc... there are no white spaces in the mysql.

Comment: what do i have to use instead?

Comment: @user2056633 `PCRE` (--> `preg_*()`). Also don't use `ext/mysql` as it's deprecated as well. Use `PDO_MYSQL`, or `MySQLi`.

Comment: This script is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: can i just replace it with preg_match ? do i need to do anything else?

Comment: I hope that this is not a production server which contains data that you want to retain. Otherwise I wish you the best at reading back all line to insert a space.

Comment: You could also try filter_var() instead of preg_replace.

Comment: i replaced all the ereg_replace with preg_replace and I got 0 in all the fileds in my form!!!! any suggestions?

Comment: @user2056633 is your question solved?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$errorMsg = "";
// First we check to see if the form has been submitted 
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    //Connect to the database through our include 
    include_once "scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
    // Filter the posted variables
    $username = filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $country = filter_var($_POST['country'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $state = filter_var($_POST['state'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $city = filter_var($_POST['city'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $accounttype = filter_var($_POST['accounttype'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_var(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $password = filter_var($_POST['password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    // Check to see if the user filled all fields with
    // the "Required"(*) symbol next to them in the join form
    // and print out to them what they have forgotten to put in
    if ((!$username) || (!$country) || (!$state) || (!$city) || (!$accounttype) || (!$email) || (!$password) || (!passport)) {

        $errorMsg = "You did not submit the following required information!<br /><br />";
        if (!$username) {
            $errorMsg .= "--- User Name";
        } else if (!$country) {
            $errorMsg .= "--- Country";
        } else if (!$state) {
            $errorMsg .= "--- State";
        } else if (!$city) {
            $errorMsg .= "--- City";
        } else if (!$accounttype) {
            $errorMsg .= "--- Account Type";
        } else if (!$email) {
            $errorMsg .= "--- Email Address";
        } else if (!$password) {
            $errorMsg .= "--- Password";
        } else if (!$passport) {
            $errorMsg .= "--- Passport";
        }
    } else {
        // Database duplicate Fields Check
        $sql_username_check = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1");
        $sql_email_check = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1");
        $username_check = mysql_num_rows($sql_username_check);
        $email_check = mysql_num_rows($sql_email_check);
        if ($username_check > 0) {
            $errorMsg = "<u>ERROR:</u><br />Your User Name is already in use inside our system. Please try another.";
        } else if ($email_check > 0) {
            $errorMsg = "<u>ERROR:</u><br />Your Email address is already in use inside our system. Please try another.";
        } else {
            // Add MD5 Hash to the password variable
            $hashedPass = md5($password);
            // Add user info into the database table, claim your fields then values 
            $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (username, country, state, city, accounttype, email, password, passport, signupdate) 
        VALUES('" . $username . "','" . $country . "','" . $state . "','" . $city . "','" . $accounttype . "','" . $email . "','" . $hashedPass . "','" . $passport . "',now())") or die(mysql_error());
            // Get the inserted ID here to use in the activation email
            $id = mysql_insert_id();
            // Create directory(folder) to hold each user files(pics, MP3s, etc.) 
            mkdir("memberFiles/$id", 0755);
            // Start assembly of Email Member the activation link
            $to = "$email";
            // Change this to your site admin email
            $from = "admin@somewebsite.com";
            $subject = "Complete your registration";
            //Begin HTML Email Message where you need to change the activation URL inside
            $message = '<html>
        <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        Hi ' . $username . ',
        <br /><br />
        You must complete this step to activate your account with us.
        <br /><br />
        Please click here to activate now &gt;&gt;
        <a href="http://www.netolancer.co.uk/bitcoin/activation.php?id=' . $id . '">
        ACTIVATE NOW</a>
        <br /><br />
        Your Login Data is as follows: 
        <br /><br />
        E-mail Address: ' . $email . ' <br />
        Password: ' . $password . ' 
        <br /><br /> 
        Thanks! 
        </body>
        </html>';
            // end of message
            $headers = "From:" . $from . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
            // Finally send the activation email to the member
            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
            // Then print a message to the browser for the joiner 
            print "<br /><br /><br /><h4>OK" . $firstname . ", one last step to verify your email identity:</h4><br />
        We just sent an Activation link to:" . $email . "<br /><br />
        <strong><font color=\"#990000\">Please check your email inbox in a moment</font></strong> to click on the Activation <br />
        Link inside the message. After email activation you can log in.";
            exit(); // Exit so the form and page does not display, just this success message
        } // Close else after database duplicate field value checks
    } // Close else after missing vars check
} //Close if $_POST
mysql_close();
?>
```

I have the impression that you have left out a very large part of your code. For instance the error message variable is not used inside your code after it is set. I haven't taken the time to change everything to mysqli. But I like to encourage you to make the switch. Please not that I haven't test the code, so that part is up to you.